# Can we call one iphone app from another iphone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Say, that i am clicking on one iphone app icon,when launched  it will create one .app file.So is it possible to call one more iphone app from that app.Or can we do something in that .app file such that it will call another app.

Answer (score 2):

Yes: you need use [URL Schemes](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationEnvironment/ApplicationEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50):

Essentially, one app registers the fact that it handles a particular URL prefix, and then to launch that app, you have to navigate to that URL.

You can pass parameters through this URL too

Comment: will u plz share a link that has an example

Answer (score 0):

If by calling another app, you mean to use other app as a service then No. One iPhone app can not communicate with another iPhone app.

The best you can do is launch another iPhone app from you app. You need to know the URL for that other app. If you want other apps to launch your app then you need to register a URL for your app so that other apps can launch your iphone app using that url.

Please note here the app will only launch if it is already installed on the iPhone. It will not automatically get it from iTunes.